What is the preferred way to manipulate log message body
I have multiline log files like this one.
2024-05-01 00:00:00.000 [INFO] TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
2024-05-01 00:00:00.005 [DEBUG] TEST4
TEST5
TEST6
2024-05-01 00:00:00.010 [WARN] TEST7
TEST8
TEST9

I am extracting each log message and meta information. So, it works fine.
Here is a config:
receivers:
  filelog:
    include:
      - /output/so.log
    start_at: beginning
    include_file_name: true
    multiline:
      line_start_pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s'
    operators:
      - type: regex_parser
        regex: '^(?P<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\s*\[(?P<severity>.*?)\s*\]\s*(?P<body>.*)'
        timestamp:
          parse_from: attributes.timestamp
          layout: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L'
          location: CET
        severity:
          parse_from: attributes.severity
      - type: remove
        field: attributes.severity
      - type: remove
        field: attributes.timestamp

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed

service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: info
    metrics:
      level: none
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers:
        - filelog
      exporters:
        - debug

Result looks like this
Resource SchemaURL:
ScopeLogs #0
ScopeLogs SchemaURL:
InstrumentationScope
LogRecord #0
ObservedTimestamp: 2024-05-02 07:42:53.846409064 +0000 UTC
Timestamp: 2024-04-30 22:00:00.01 +0000 UTC
SeverityText: WARN
SeverityNumber: Warn(13)
Body: Str(2024-05-01 00:00:00.010 [WARN] TEST7
TEST8
TEST9)
Attributes:
     -> log.file.name: Str(so.log)
     -> body: Str(TEST7)
Trace ID:
Span ID:
Flags: 0
        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "debug"}

My goal is to strip body message and retain only log message excluding the timestamp and severity, since this data is captured in separate attributes.
regex_parser operator should help with that, but it does not work with multiline logs.
Can you suggest how to achive this? Might be there are other processor that can help?
The config for opentelemetry collector is attached.
